# Is there something I should know about the jquery .text method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm learning about the [.data method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) and saw this in the code:

```
$("span").text("" + value);
```

Q: Is there a reason why the author put ("" + value) instead of simply (value)?

Comment: Seems more like the author is used to work with other languages that need an explicit string cast and carried it over JQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why does it happen in this particular demo?  because these differ:

```
$("span").text(undefined);      //empty string set
$("span").text("" + undefined); //"undefined" set
```

Before `.data()` is set, the value is `undefined`, and it needs to be converted to a string to see anything in the output.

---

*More generally:* Yes, there *are* cases where it matters, let's take a quick example that fails:

```
$("span").text([1, 2, 3, 4]);
```

This will fail because it's a different overload of `.text()` (*many* things have array overloads) rather than this:

```
$("span").text("" + [1, 2, 3, 4]);
```

Which *does* work, it's effectively:

```
$("span").text("" + "1,2,3,4");
```

Comment: what do you mean with "fail" here ?

Comment: @jAndy - it won't display "undefined" in the output, it'd be empty instead, making an awkward demo.

Comment: Deleted my previous comment. My test was obviously flawed. Coulda sworn I changed it to `"body"`.

Comment: @NickCraver: sounds pretty subjective to me whether to call it "wrong behavior" (fail) or not.

Comment: @jAndy - I guess I should be clearer in saying "this won't at all do what you were after"...I consider that failing, given the purpose is a demo :)

Comment: @NickCraver: Now the question is, isn't it enough for a method which calls itself `text()` to try it's best to display the passed value/number. If you pass in an array with intent, you should get exactly the current behavior. But that is one mans oppinion.

Answer (score 1):

A: no, it makes no sense to have this explicit "cast" into a string. jQuery will take care of you.

Comment: This isn't true, for a lot of cases.